# How to add an all rule to this Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to just type 'make all' and have the following Makefile do everything it's supposed to do:

```
LEX = lex
YACC = yacc
CC = gcc

calcu: y.tab.o lex.yy.o
    $(CC) -o calcu y.tab.o lex.yy.o -ly -lfl

y.tab.c y.tab.h: parser.y
    $(YACC) -d parser.y

y.tab.o: y.tab.c parser.h
    $(CC) -c y.tab.c

lex.yy.o: y.tab.h lex.yy.c 
    $(CC) -c lex.yy.c

lex.yy.c: calclexer.l parser.h
    $(LEX) calclexer.l

clean:
    rm *.o
    rm *.c
    rm calcu
```

Comment: Please, specify "make" tag instead of "makefile". More info:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24030/why-do-they-specify-makefile-tag-instead-of-make/26567#26567

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What all is it supposed to do? If you just want it to build `calcu`, all you have to do is type `make` and it will make it along with everything it depends on, because it is the first rule in the file.

If you still want to make an `all` rule, it can be done like this. I recommend putting this above all other rules, so that you can just type `make` instead of `make all`.

```
all: calcu
```

Comment: .PHONY: all  

This tells make that you don't expect there to actually be a file named "all" after building.